# pandas groupby and update the sum of the number of times the values in one column is greater than the other column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset in the following format

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'Label1', 0, 8, 2], [1, 'Label3', 0, 20, 5], [2, 'Label5', 1, 20, 2], [2, 'Label4', 1, 11, 0], 
              [5, 'Label2', 0, 0, -4],[1, 'Label2', 1, 8, 2], [2, 'Label5', 0, 20, 5], [3, 'Label2', 1, 20, 2], [4, 'Label4', 0, 1, 0], 
              [5, 'Label3', 0, 1, -4],[1, 'Label3', 1, 8, 2], [2, 'Label4', 0, 20, 5], [3, 'Label1', 1, 20, 2], [4, 'Label3', 0, 1, 0], 
              [5, 'Label4', 0, 1, -4],[1, 'Label4', 1, 8, 2], [2, 'Label3', 0, 20, 5], [3, 'Label3', 1, 20, 2], [4, 'Label5', 0, 1, 0], 
              [5, 'Label5', 0, 1, -4]],
              columns=['ID', 'Label', 'Status', 'Coeff', 'result'])

cm = {'TP': 0,'FP': 0}
```

For each `ID` in df, I would like to find the number of times the column `Coeff` is greater than `Result` when `Status` column is 1. If this count is greater than 3 then `TP` should be incremented by 1 and if it less than 3, then `FP` should be incremented by 1.

Example: When `ID` is 1111 and `Status` 1, if the `Coeff` column is greater than `Result` column twice for that particular ID, then FP must be incremented by 1.

I tried to add a new column called count for each ID and assigned a value as 1 everytime the column `Coeff` was greater than `Result`.

```
for ID in df.groupby('ID'): 
  df.loc[(df['Coeff'] > df['Result']), 'count'] = 1
  df_new = list(df[['ID','count']].groupby(df['ID']))
```

Then I thought of finding whether `count` has the number 1 in it. If it does, then increment `TP`. Otherwise, increment `FP`.

But I couldn't achieve it.

How do I get the required result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple grouping operation on a masked comparison should do:

```
v = df.Coeff.gt(df.result).where(df.Status.astype(bool)).groupby(df.ID).sum()
```

Or (to retain `dtype=int`, thanks piR!),

```
v = df.Coeff.gt(df.result).where(df.Status.astype(bool), 0).groupby(df.ID).sum()
```

```
v   # second expression result

ID
1    3
2    2
3    3
4    0
5    0
dtype: int64
```

Now,

```
cm['TP'] = v.gt(3).sum()
cm['FP'] = v.lt(3).sum()
```

*Details*
`df.Coeff.gt(df.result)` returns a mask. Now, hide all those values for which `df.Status` is not 1. This is done using `(df.Coeff > df.result).where(df.Status.astype(bool))`. Finally, take this masked result, and group on `ID`, followed by a sum to get your result.

Comment: `df.Coeff.gt(df.result).where(df.Status.astype(bool), 0).groupby(df.ID).sum()`

Comment: @piRSquared Is replacing with 0 more efficient?

Comment: Preference because it keeps dtype int